# FindItemWithText getting the string in listview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a working code. But with a very little problem. I don't know why it is not getting the text in listview as string.

here is my code that has problem:

```
Private Sub ListView2_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView2.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim ChkContact As New ListViewItem

    ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText(listview2.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text)

    If ChkContact IsNot Nothing Then
        txtContact.Text = ChkContact.SubItems(1).Text
        ListView2.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text = ChkContact.SubItems(1).Text

    Else
        txtContact.Text = "no match found"
        ListView2.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text = "Not in the list"
    End If

End Sub
```

if I change this code

```
ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText(listview2.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text)
```

to this

```
ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText("1234") 'with this it is working
```

thanks ....

Comment: or maybe to convert the value of subitem into string...

Comment: I also try this ChkContact = lvContact.FindItemWithText(chr (34) & listview2.FocusedItem.Subitem(1).text & chr(34))